# using the preposition "OF" multiple times when listing things in parallel

Tags: prepositions, usage

> Writing is very much a processing **of** recording ideas for yourself in
> notes and then **of** preparing to share those ideas with others in some
> written form.

This sentence is cited from a guide book by Oxford.

I always omit the preposition "of" after the first one when I am listing multiple things. Is it wrong, or it is okay to omit it?

Comment: What research have you done? If you're unfamiliar with what to search for, try "conjunction reduction". It has been discussed several times on this site, and you can find explanations elsewhere on the Internet, too.

Answer (score 0):

“And” can be used to make lists of anything, so long as they are parallel.

> Writing is very much a process* of recording ideas, of preparing to share those ideas, and of following through.

*or*

> Writing is very much a process of recording ideas, preparing to share those ideas, and following through.

A list of prepositional phrases is probably *less* conventional than a prepositional phrase where the object is a list, and so tends to set off each item.  That can be rhetorically useful if you are trying to say “this important thing and this other, also-important thing, plus this third very important thing” — as opposed to “this big undifferentiated collection of things”.

Compare the different stress here:

> Writing is very much a process of recording ideas, a process of preparing to share those ideas, and a process of following through.

This emphasizes the multifaceted nature of writing, rather than framing it as a neat series of steps.

* “Processing” in your original quote is a typo.  It should be “process”.